# Set UUID when generating a VMDK image from a raw image using qemu-img

Tags: virtualbox, freebsd, qemu, conversion, disk-image

It is possible to convert a raw image to a VMDK image with `qemu-img` like this:

```bsh
qemu-img convert -O vmdk "$_raw" "$_vmdk"
```

I know it is possible to set UUID of the generated VMDK image with:

```bsh
VBoxManage internalcommands sethduuid "$_vmdk" "$_uuid"
```

Is there a way to set the UUID of the disk as it is being converted with `qemu-img` (would be great if the solution worked on FreeBSD)?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is from the top of my head and is *not* tested. If you test it feel free to update the answer.

Unfortunately the question have very little context to explain why we are doing this. At face value we could just refer to [qemu-img](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?qemu-img) and give the answer: No.

But that would be boring. Let us instead make some wild assumptions and run with it.

What you describe as a solution is possible on FreeBSD with `qemu-img` from [emulators/qemu-utils](https://www.freshports.org/emulators/qemu-utils/) and vboxmanage from [emulators/virtualbox-ose](https://www.freshports.org/emulators/virtualbox-ose/). Maybe this is what you are doing? But you do not state why this is a problem (Maybe just want to use one less tool?).

The interesting thing is then what is only implied: You are using a [GUID Partition table (GPT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) on your disk. `qemu-img` does not really care what is on the disk whereas `vboxmanage` is nice enough to have a helper function.

## As a disk

So if you have the full original copy of `/dev/ada0` as `ada0.dd` (or just a raw file born in Qemu) - then you can use the image as a virtual memory disk:

```
# mdconfig -a -t vnode -u 0 -f /home/johndoe/ada0.dd
```

This will give us `/dev/md0` which should be your full disk.

You can then check everything looks good.

```
# fdisk /dev/md0
```

This should look exactly like your old disk.

```
# glabel status
```

When working with GPT you might prefer using `gpart`

```
# gpart create -s gpt /dev/md0
```

The UUID is created automatically with this command. I do not know if it actually touches the entries in the partition table. In that case make a backup first. Maybe destroy the full table - create and then restore? You will need to do some testing here. But the point is that you now have full access to the drive.

You can mount the filesystem using [this method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/571302/74393) as well

## As a file

When we examine the GUID Partition Table Schematics from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) we are told that we find the Disk GUID in mixed endian in the partition table header at offset 56.

[image: GUID Partition Table Scheme]

So rather than mounting the disk image we can simply treat them as a bunch of bytes. I assume that you are using 512 byte sectors but you may need to adjust for 4K sectors. The header is then at LBA 1 and we are interested in offset 56 - thus 512 + 56 = 568

```
$ hexdump -v -s 568 -n 16 -e '1/1 "%.2x\n"' /home/johndoe/ada0.dd
```

We can then simply change the needed bytes. Hexdump is not quite enough for this and you should have a look at [xxd](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xxd) which comes with [editors/vim](https://www.freshports.org/editors/vim/). [uuidgen](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=uuidgen) can help you generate a proper GUID.

If you go down this route then please observe:

- Make your script resilliant by checking for the signature "EFI PART" before writing anything
- Remember that you have the secondary copy of the header which needs to be corrected as well (Find it via offset 32)

That would be a fun little script to write.

## Streaming

I have a sneaky suspicion that what you really want is to keep the original raw image pristine and do things on the fly. We are partly there as `xxd` supports both `stdin` and `stdout` so we could pipe trough it. Unfortunately it does not look like `qemu-img` supports `stdin`.

Then we have to have a file on disk. The pragmatic solution would be to have the original file as backup and a new copy used for modifications. This will only have the cost of added diskspace.

But as you are on FreeBSD you have a screaming fast way to save the diskspace and avoid doing a copy. You can use ZFS to your advantage. Simply create a new dataset where you place your raw image files and do a snapshot. Then you can modify the file directly but it will only affect the bytes changed (or rather the changed sectors). When done you quickly revert those sectors by rolling back the snapshot.

As we do not want to snapshot everything we create a specific dataset

```
# zfs create zroot/rawfiles
```

We place whatever data we need into `/rawfiles` and create a snapshot for our clean state.

```
# zfs snapshot zroot/rawfiles@cleanstate
```

We can then modify a few bytes in our potentially large image files. When we want to get back to our clean state the we roll back.

```
# zfs rollback zroot/rawfiles@cleanstate
```

If you have space contraints then this is a fast and viable option. If you do something like this then beware of race conditions if you keep rolling back.

If you do it as a backup "just in case" then you can skip creating a seperate dataset and just do `zfs snapshot zroot@hailmary`. If things blow up then just `cp /.zfs/snapshot/hailmary/......`

## Manually

If you have influence on the image creation process we have some fun options as well.

We can use `qemu-img` to create a new image, mount it and create the GPT (with a new GUID)

```
# qemu-img create -f raw VM10G.raw 10G
# mdconfig -a -t vnode -u 0 -f VM10G.raw
# gpart create -s gpt /dev/md0
```

But as it is just a file we do not need `qemu-img`.

```
# truncate -s 10g VM10G.raw
# mdconfig -a -t vnode -u 0 -f VM10G.raw
# gpart create -s gpt /dev/md0
```

See [building a UFS bootable image from scratch](https://hackmd.io/@dch/SJRD7QRNE?type=view)

Why am I showing this? Well, maybe you are doing something along those lines. Then we have a pretty neat trick when on FreeBSD: [mkimg(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mkimg&sektion=1).

With this you can create disk images on FreeBSD and it supports QCOW, QCOW2, Dynamic VHD, Fixed VHD, VMDK and RAW. This mean that you can go directly to VMDK.

```
mkimg -f vmdk -s gpt -b /boot/pmbr -p freebsd-boot:=/boot/gptboot -p freebsd-ufs:=root-file-system.ufs -p freebsd-swap::1G -o gpt.vmdk
```

The example is FreeBSD centric but it is using raw partitions. So if you change your source from the raw full disk image to just partition images you should have a viable route.