# Shrink ufs partition in OpenBSD

Tags: partition, openbsd, gparted

I have just installed OpenBSD and I need to free some space for another system. Earlier I did it with `gparted`, but here is not an option. `fdisk` only can grow partitions filling the subsequent free space. So is there any replacement of `gparted` for OpenBSD or how can I accomplish it via command line applications.

Answer (score 1):

UFS does not support shrinking directly, like you're trying with gparted. You'll need to create a new partition, mount it, dump and then restore. Please read this - [Shrink FreeBSD partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/571270/shrink-freebsd-partition)

**Always make sure you have backup when resizing partitions**